# Let $S_n =\sum$(entries of $A^n$). Prove that $\log(S_n)/n$ converges to the logarithm of the eigenvalue of $A$ with largest modulus.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, limits, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, logarithms

Let $A$ be a non-negative, non-zero, square matrix and define $S_n=\sum$(entries of $A^n$). Let $\lambda$ be the eigenvalue of $A$ with the largest modulus. How do I prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\log(S_n)=\log(\lambda)?$$

I tried to do something with the following fact, but I got stuck: If $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, then $\lambda_1^n,\ldots,\lambda_k^n$ are the eigenvalues of $A^{n}$.

(Also: what if $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}$?)

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that $A \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times p}$ is diagonalizable, so that we can write the eigenvalue-eigenvector decomposition:

$$A=PDP^{-1} \ \ implying \ \ A^n=PD^nP^{-1}\tag{1}$$

where $D=\operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1,\ldots, \lambda_p)$ with

$$|\lambda_1|>|\lambda_2|\geq\cdots\geq |\lambda_p|.$$

The equality you have to establish is equivalent to this one :

$$\text{for } n \to \infty, \ \ \ S_n \approx K \lambda_1^n \tag{$*$}$$

(where $K$ is a certain constant).

Let $C_i \ \ (i=1, \ldots,p)$ be the **columns of $P$** and $L_j \ \ (j=1,\ldots,p)$ be the **lines of $P^{-1}$**.

Relationship $(1)$ can be written as the following combination of rank-one matrices:

$$A^n=\sum_{i=1}^p \lambda_i^nC_iL_i\tag{3}$$

As the first matrix "dwarves" the other ones when $n \to \infty$,

$$A^n \approx \lambda_1^n\,\underbrace{C_1L_1}_{M_1}\tag{4}$$

If $K$ is the sum of all elements of $M_1$, we obtain in this way relationship $(*).$

Comment: First of all, thanks for your reply! I dont really understand your equation labeled by (3). To me it looks like that the left hand side is a matrix and the right hand side is a number. Also, you use the index $n$ twice: for the power of $A$ and the dimensions of $A$.

Comment: You are right. Sorry for that. I have corrected this two mathematical lapsus linguae (I have now permuted the rôle of lines and columns and I distinguish an $n$ and a $p$) and completed the proof. That's what happens when one write things in a hurry.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Hardy for TeX improvements.